# Converting a baby - When to do Circumcision

Tags: minor-katan-child, conversion-to-judaism, brit-milah, age, baby-infant

I know that one can convert an infant (and if he doesn't recant when he becomes of age, the conversion is retractively chal) but what about milah? For a Jewish child, milah before the 8th day isn't a valid milah and hatafat dam brit would have to be done at the proper time. But a non-jewish child isn't commanded to get a milah so it would seem that there is no obligation to do so on the 8th day specifically. (By the way, this is not a duplicate of the comments in [Why Not Eight Days Until a Convert's Circumcision?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12789/why-not-eight-days-until-a-converts-circumcision)) This site http://www.convert.org/Converting_Infants.html reads, regarding converting a newborn, "If possible, this should be done on the 8th day after the birth of the boy. If a circumcision has already been performed, a drop of blood needs to be drawn in a ceremony called hatafat dam brit." but no source is given. Why would there be a requirement to wait till the eighth day? A Jewish baby lives through one shabbat (i.e. 7 day cycle) before a brit but the non-Jewish baby has no connection to shabbat.

Is it that, objectively, there is something halachicaly about being alive 8 days for any human that then makes milah viable (I don't mean medically and I'm not sure if the kabbalistic notion of "positive and negative energies" http://www.nymohel.com/laws_customs.php#p16 is an answer I, as a layman, can truly appreciate).

Comment: Can anyone verify the claim of convert.org?

Comment: Why do you think Shabbat has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.aish.com/ci/sam/48964686.html

> Devarim Rabbah 6:1 states that God had pity on the child and instead
>   of requiring circumcision immediately after birth, waited until the
>   baby was stronger. This strength may be physical (Moreh Nevuchim 3:49)
>   or spiritual (as discussed above regarding the Sabbath). Other reasons
>   given are so that the baby is given time to "mourn" for the Torah that
>   it learned in utero and has now forgotten (Taz, Yoreh Deah265:13), and
>   that the parents are happier at eight days when "tumas leidah" no
>   longer applies (Nidda 31b). **Interestingly, the baby's coagulation
>   factors appear to peak at the eighth day.** See the essay entitled "A
>   Tapestry of Eights" in Bris Milah by Rabbi Paysach Krohn (Mesorah
>   Publications) for a detailed discussed of the significance of the
>   eighth day for circumcision.

Comment: Thank you -- I knew about the coagulation bit but was trying to avoid the medical explanation. Only the moreh nevuchim, it seems, gives a reason which would apply to a non-Jewish baby and that reason is simply physical.