# Could someone who has committed a heinous crime convert to Judaism?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, sin, historical-figures, repentance-teshuvah

Is there any reason that someone who has committed horrible sins in the past (for example, mass murder) could not become a Jew? Assume, of course, that the sinner/criminal is willing to do teshuvah for his actions.

It would seem that, for example, certain historical figures placed themselves beyond the pale of ever being able to become a Jew, even if they had repented in their lifetimes. Is it correct that such people would have been categorically forbidden from becoming Jews? If so, at what level of sin is that line drawn?

Comment: There is no such thing as being unable to repent. Which historical figures are you referring to?

Comment: Well, one in particular comes to mind. But jutky's answer would suggest that even he could have become Jewish if he had done teshuvah in his lifetime. Correct?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/does-a-convert-have-a-clean-slate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Anyone can convert to Judaism.

We find an example in [Gittin 57:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=57b&format=pdf) that Nevuzardan killed millions of jews and then converted.

Comment: Interesting, though, considering the statement from the Gemara I quoted in my answer: would the Sanhedrin have still put him to death for those murders?

Comment: @Alex Would kind of warning would you give him?

Comment: @DoubleAA: there's no shogeg for a ben Noach, "because he should have learned [that this action is forbidden] and didn't do so" (Rambam, Hil. Melachim 10:2). So it sounds like no warning is needed.

Comment: @Alex But you might need warning to have him killed after conversion.

Comment: @DoubleAA: doesn't look like it. See Rashi to Sanhedrin 71b, ד"ה הואיל and ד"ה לישראל, that hasraah would indeed have been needed had he committed these acts after his conversion, but not before.

Comment: I would be extremely hesitant mixing halakha with aggada (think bleach and ammonium...)

Answer (score 9):

A halachic source that bears on this is [Rambam, Hil. Melachim 10:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188355/jewish/Chapter-10.htm) (from [Sanhedrin 71b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=71b&format=pdf)):

> A gentile who converts after cursing G-d's name, worshipping false gods, engaging in relations with a colleague's wife, or killing a fellow gentile is exempt from punishment.
>
> In contrast, if he converted after killing a Jew or having relations with a Jew's wife, he is liable...

So we see that he can indeed be accepted as a convert.