# Faster than Light Alien Spaceships

Tags: shoftim--book-of, outer-space

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9204/2642) explains how there is support for the idea that aliens could exist from a few respected sources, based on the understanding of [Shoftim 5:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.5.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en),

> 'Curse ye Meroz', said the angel of the LORD, 'Curse ye bitterly the inhabitants thereof, because they came not to the help of the LORD, to the help of the LORD against the mighty.'

If we accept this idea, how did Devora and Barak know that these aliens exist?  Does this mean that they had visited Earth and they had seen them and communicated with them?

Even if there was another way that Devora and Barak were aware of them, how would the aliens be aware of the battle that they should be cursed for not helping?

Also, how would the aliens manage to travel and to arrive in time to help with the battle?  Devora and Barak would be familiar with the idea that long-distance travel takes a long time, and they wouldn't curse them unless they thought that they could attend.

So **if we accept the premise that they were referring to aliens**, does this not imply that either: -

1. The Merozians were somehow able to be aware of what is going on on Earth and to travel here in time to be involved (ie. some kind of faster than light spaceship or wormhole travel or something)?, or
2. They were already here?

(nb. this is not the same as either of my recent questions - [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139242/can-aliens-really-not-have-free-will) or [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139278/if-the-merozians-dont-have-free-will-then-why-did-devorah-and-barak-curse-them), but is related)

Comment: Maybe Meroz = Mars? Or there used to be a spaceship parked in geosynchronous orbit called Meroz?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Meroz does sound a lot like Mars, allowing for transliteration creep, but we're still discussing alien spaceships!

Comment: @MosesSupposes מאדים is mars

Comment: Although this will sound like pseudo-science, consider the idea of "the speed of thought". On a certain plane of existence, if you picture in your mind a very distant location that you are familiar with, you traverse that distance instantaneously. Sound wild? Consider the amount of tax dollars that have been spent on "Remote Viewing" by the military. Prophecy is also related to this thought realm. So in this context, vast physical distances don't pose such an obstacle. The Torah also discusses the phenomena of spatial contraction, covering vast distances in very short periods of time.

Comment: For those unfamiliar, spatial contraction is the concept of "folding space" ala Dune and the Spacing Guild. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Guild

Comment: מִן־שָׁמַ֖יִם נִלְחָ֑מוּ הַכּֽוֹכָבִים֙ מִמְּסִלּוֹתָ֔ם נִלְחֲמ֖וּ עִם־סִֽיסְרָֽא׃
The stars fought from heaven,From their courses they fought against Sisera.

https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.5.20

Comment: for additional background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive

Comment: "This answer explains how there is support for the idea that aliens could exist from a few respected sources, **based on the understanding of Shoftim 5:23**" unless I missed something, that is that individual contributor's own pet theory (user Adam Simon). I don't see him citing any sources claiming that Meroz is inhabited by aliens. He presents the Gemara, says that one *could* interpret it that way, and then cites sources in support of the possibility of the existence of aliens (which is a different analysis).

Comment: So unless I misunderstood something, you are requesting us to corroborate Adam Simon not "respected sources"

Comment: @Shababnik I know, but some things have multiple names.  For 5:20 are you suggesting some kind of ranged interplanetary/interstellar weaponry?

Comment: @Deuteronomy Aryeh Kaplan Reader p.171 "...the opinion of the Sefer Habris who states that extraterrestrial life does exist..." "...The proof that he brings for his thesis is most ingenious.  In the song of Deborah, we find the verse (Judges 5:23), "Cursed is Meroz...cursed are its inhabitants." In theTalmud, we find an opinion, that Meroz is the name of a star.  According to this opinion..." "...is clear proof from the words of our Sages for extraterrestrial life." (I've cut out bits to keep within word count of comments). This is referred to in Adam Simon's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That post is somewhat misleadingly composed. So in truth, it is based on ONE specific source (I'll leave the stature weighing of the sefer to others). That is different than claiming that multiple sources, respected no less, have offered up this reading of the Gemara. IMHO your Q would more appropriately be reframed as an attempt to understand the unique view of R. Pinhas Eliyahu Horowitz of Vilna (author of Sefer ha-Berith).