# If a gentile commited murder and then converted, can he be executed?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, murder, noachide-laws, capital-punishment

Assuming these are witnesses who warned him of the penalty immediately before he acted, as specified in Sanhedrin, if a gentile committed murder (or any other violation of the Noachide Law) and then converted, and in a couple of years the witnesses of the original murder show up to testify:

Can he be convicted and executed?

If so, by what execution method does he die?

Would the type of execution depend on the type of violation?

Comment: dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6429/759

Comment: @DoubleAA But the source cited in the answer below is a direct opposite of the ones in the referenced question :) - can we merge the two?

Comment: @DoubleAA overlapping concepts, but not completely so, in that this one only addresses murder, and addresses penalty concepts that the other doesn't. I'd say not a dupe, but certainly related. Answers to this could refer to answers to that.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Murder makes it more specific, so still a dupe. Is penalty really that different from liability?

Comment: @DoubleAA, actually, the other question is about Teshuva, which sounds like between the individual and God, while this one is explicitly about what what a court may do. A priori, there's no reason to assume that answers to these would be identical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Chemdas Yisroel (R' Meir Dan Plozky Zatzal) 42](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21649&st=&pgnum=217&hilite=) says that in such a case the convert would not be executed.

Comment: This is a great source, very xomprehensive :). Covers galus for homicide and theft as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The *Mishneh Torah*, in [Hilkhot Melakhim u-Milchamot 10:6-7[4-5]](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e510.htm#6), says:

> **ו  [ד]** בן נוח שבירך את השם, או שעבד עבודה זרה, או שבא על אשת חברו, או שהרג חברו, ונתגייר--פטור.  הרג בן ישראל, או שבא על אשת ישראל, ונתגייר--חייב; והורגין אותו על בן ישראל, וחונקין אותו על אשת ישראל שבעל--שהרי נשתנה דינו.
>
> **ז  [ה]** כבר ביארנו שכל מיתת בני נוח בסיף--אלא אם כן בעל אשת ישראל נערה מאורסה, ייסקל, ואם בעלה אחר שנכנסה לחופה קודם שתיבעל, ייחנק

In English( based on [Eliyahu Touger's translation](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188355/jewish/Chapter-10.htm)):

> **6[4]** A gentile who converts after cursing God's name, worshiping false gods, engaging in relations with a colleague's wife, or killing a fellow gentile is exempt from punishment.
>
> In contrast, if he converted after killing a Jew or having relations with a Jew's wife, he is liable. He is decapitated for killing the Jew and strangled to death for engaging in relations with a Jew's wife. He is given the latter punishment because the laws governing him have changed.
>
> **7[5]** It has already been explained that gentiles are always executed by decapitation except in cases when one engages in relations with the wife of a Jew while she is a consecrated maiden. In the latter instance, he is stoned to death.
>
> If he engaged in relations with a Jew's wife after they married, but before they ever engaged in relations, he is executed by strangulation.

In short:

- If a *Ben No'ach* violated one of his laws, involving only himself( e.g. *Avodah Zarah*) or other *Benei No'ach*, if he converts, he is exempt from punishment.
- If he committed the violation against a Jew, even if he converts, he is punished:

  - In general, he is executed by decapitation( by sword).
  - If he engages in relations with the wife of a Jew:

    - if while she is a consecrated maiden, he is stoned.
    - if after she is married, he is strangled.

---

I edited the translation, and summarized, based on the *Moachon Mamre* edition's version. In [printed text](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=83&perek=10&halocha=5) it says a *Ben No'ach* who converts is stoned for engaging "in relations with the wife of a Jew **or** a consecrated maiden"(אלא אם בעל אשת ישראל **או** נערה מאורסה יסקל).