# How can one make repentance for things he can't remember?

Tags: sin, repentance-teshuvah, baal-teshuva, memory

Say an unmarried Baal Teshuvah at the age of 30 decided to make repentance. A lot of time has gone by and he doesn't remember who he cheated, lied to, stole from, spoke loshen hara about, and so on. In such a scenario, is there anything an individual can do to make repentance for such sins?

Does the principle of erasing of all sins upon marriage apply for such sins?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/does-a-convert-have-a-clean-slate

Comment: I think Talmud Torah but I can't remember a source.

Comment: chovos halevavos gate of repentance ch.10 http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=388#ch10 addesses this very question. bottom line is you do what you can and God does the rest.

Comment: [Devarim 29:28](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0529.htm#28)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do with stolen objects which are impossible to return?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36082/what-to-do-with-stolen-objects-which-are-impossible-to-return)