# Does a convert retain his debts to Gentiles and to Jews?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, money

Following my [previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103503/why-does-a-fresh-convert-retain-his-property),

After the conversion, does a convert Halachicly, as a newly formed Jew, keep all his existing debts to other Gentiles and Jews?

Also, is he obligated to return A Gzelah (IIRC there's a Takkanah about Baaley Teshuva)?

<sub>I'm looking for clear sources, no speculations, please.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

[Sefer Chassidim, 691](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Hasidim.691.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אע"פ שאמרו גר שנתגייר כקטן שנולד דמי מ"מ משלם מה שחייב לשלם
>
> Even though a convert is like a newly born child, nevertheless, he must pay his outstanding obligations.

According to [Rabbi Yair Bacharach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yair_Bacharach) in [Shut Chavos Ya'ir (79)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=857&pgnum=102), if a convert has in his possession an item that he stole or robbed before his conversion, he MUST return it.
However if he has in his possession, a lost object, that he found before his conversion, he does NOT have to return it.

See further discussion in [Shut Yad Elyahu (Lublin) (40)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22182&st=&pgnum=105), and [Shut Shvus Yaakov (I, 177)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1519&st=&pgnum=92).

Answer (score 5):

Rambam ([Malveh Ve'Loveh 5:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Creditor_and_Debtor.5.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> ישראל שלווה מעות מן הגוי ברבית וזקפן עליו בְּמִלְּוָה, ונתגייר, אם עד שלא נתגייר זקפן עליו במלוה, גובה את הקרן ואת הרבית. ואם משנתגייר זקפן, גובה את הקרן ואינו גובה את הרבית.

In a case where a Jew borrowed money from a gentile at interest, and then the gentile converted; If a reckoning was made before he converted, the convert may collect the principal and the interest. If a reckoning was not made until after he converted, the convert may collect the principal, but not the interest.

> אבל גוי שלווה מישראל ברבית וזקף עליו את הרבית בְּמִלְּוָה, אע"פ שזקפן עליו אחר שנתגייר, גובה את הקרן ואת הרבית, שלא יאמרו, "בשביל מעותיו נתגייר זה"; וגובה הישראלי ממנו אחר שנתגייר כל מעות הרבית שנתחייב בהן כשהיה גוי.

Different rules apply when, by contrast, a gentile borrows money from a Jew at interest and then converts. After a reckoning is made, even if it was made after the conversion, the convert is required to pay the entire sum, the principal and the interest. This measure was instituted lest people say that the person converted for the sake of his money. Even after he converted, the Jew can collect the entire sum of interest for which he became liable while he was a gentile.

Comment: A very good source, but it seems to only deals with a convert vs a Jew - half done. What about the other part - his debts to gentiles?

Answer (score 1):

The source of גר שנתגייר כקטן שנולד is Yevamos 22.

We find numerous applications to this halacha:

**Relatives** - the conversion removes the *kurva* to relatives

- **עריות**: Relations with relatives who would be *arayos* are now permitted (Yevamos 22, 97).
- **אבילות**: He is not obligated to mourn for those who were once considered close relatives. (Shulchan Aruch 374.5, Rambam Hil. Avel 2.3. See also Kovet Haaros §22 for further discussion of this application.
- **מכה אביו**: The prohibition of hitting one's father no longer applies. (Rambam Ch. 5 Mamrim)
- **ירושה**: A convert will not inherit his relatives from prior the conversion (Kiddushin 17).
- **פרו ורבו**: R' Yochanan and Reish Lakish argue whether a convert who sired children while not-Jewish has discharged his obligation for procreation (Yevamos 62).

**Accountability**

- **עונש שמים**: A convert is not punished for the sins he committed before his conversion. (Yevamos 48)
- **עונש בית דין**: A non-Jew who sins is not released from his death sentence through conversion. (Sanhedrin 71, Tos ad loc)
- **עומש שמים אחר גירותו**: The Mahari Basan in his sefer עשירית האיפה writes a tremendous *chiddush* - a convert is only punishable for sins after twenty years, because one has to be 20 years of age to be punishable in the Heavenly Court, and his 20 years begin from when he becomes *like a newborn baby*.

**Financial Law**

- **Returning stolen property**: The Chavas Yoir (§79) posits that a convert must return property he stole before his conversion, based on Tosfos that concerning Beis Din, he is fully accountable (see עונש בית דין, above). He does not have to return lost property found while still a gentile.
- **Repaying debts:** Shu"t Yad Eliyahu §40 rules that he is no longer obligated to pay his loans. However, the Rambam (Malve veLove 5:6) rules that he is still obligated to pay loans to a Jew. (Regadring debts to a non-Jew, see Shu"t Shoel UMeishiv V1, §128)

**Other**

- **טומאת זב**: Although one who has a *keri* emission cannot become a *zav*, if a gentile has a seminal emission and subsequently converts, he can become a *zav* immediately. (Rambam, Pirush Hamishne, Zav 2.3)
- **איסור אשת איש לבועל**: A women who commits adultery with a gentile is permitted to marry him after his conversion, although there is normally a prohibition in marrying the adulterer. (Mordechai Sanhedrin §620)
- **נדרים**: He is not beholden to vows made as a gentile. (Beis Yitzchok O"CH §92.3)

Comment: Regarding financial obligations, IIRC, the Steipler in Kisvei Kehilas Yackov (Yevamos 47) discusses how far the din *koton shenolad* helps.