# Good idea to fast on the day of conversion?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, fast-days

Is there any reason someone would refrain from eating on the day of conversion up until it is complete?

Comment: If someone ate while a non-Jew and then converted immediately afterwards, there may be a shailah as to whether he must say an after beracha.

Comment: that's another interesting point but not what my question is about. If someone were to be going through a gerus they are starting a new life. Another event would be marriage in which a couple are starting a new life together and fast up until the chuppah is complete.

Comment: It sounds like a logical comparison and basically answers your own question. Whilst there may be no compulsion or custom to fast, I see no reason why a person shouldn't fast voluntarily if he feels it's appropriate.

Comment: ["fasting may be required before swimming or taking a bath to prevent accidental drowning"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21905572)

Answer (score 5):

[Tshuvos Vhanhogos 2:506](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=419&hilite=) in the name of Seridai Aish 2:108 says that there are some when converting that fast on the day of immersion. However Tshuvos Vhanhogos says that a convert should only fast up until the immersion, as after that it is a Yom Tov for him and it is inappropriate to fast then. The reason is that similar to a groom who fasts on the day of his wedding as his sins are forgiven.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true though http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6429/759

Comment: @DoubleAA: Interesting. Perhaps that is why not all do so, as he clearly says that there are "some".