# Converts like newborn children

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, lomdus

there is the principle גר שנתגייר כקטן שנולד דמי
does anyone know of commentaries on that ?
Is it just a legal principle, or does it mean that there is an ontological change
(i.e., is the convert just CONSIDERED like a newborn child legally speaking (without precedent legal ties), or is he IN FACT a (spiritually) newly born ?)

Comment: Related (dupe?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6429/5

Comment: Baal teshuba so
see Tehilim. D. M. wants Lev Tahor Ruach Nachon.
What is IN FACT, a magical phenomenon?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the statement has Halachis implications. For example:

1. Does a convert who had children before converting need to have more children [Yevamos 62a](http://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62a?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all)
2. Does a child born before conversion prevent the "first born son" born after the conversion from being considered a first born [Yevamos 62a](http://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62a?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all)
3. Are brothers from before conversion considered brothers [Yevamos 97b](http://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.97b?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all)

But [it](http://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.48b.60?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) also says that (at least according to one opinion), a convert is forgiven for all his sins from prior to conversion

Comment: Technically, Rashi only says that he will not be punished; not that he has been forgiven. The two are nearly identical, but not identical.

Comment: I may be mistaken but I recall the Rambam saying something about a ger would not be forgiven for an avera they would have been guilty of capital punishment for while they weren't Jewish just by converting

Comment: @Dude we follow the other opinions

Answer (score -2):

It says in the posuk גר שנתגיר a convert that converted now if he was a convert why did he need to convert the wording of the posuk is a bit interesting the explanation is that every convert essentially when he was born had the capacity being one his souls phycie is different it is naturally spirtully intuned in other words god use these Jews as alreathis part of they just have to reveal this part of themselves this is the deeper meaning of that Passage

Comment: What Pasuk is this? I can't find it.

Comment: sorry its not a pasuk its many loshen hagemara likw gemara shabbos 68b and btw this vort is sourced teshuvas maharam merotenburg chida marochos 3 ois 3 also in sefer teshuvas balei tosfos why the negatives

Comment: This answer is very unclear. Please attempt to edit with clearer language, punctuation, and grammar.

Comment: this video explains this answer clearly... http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/livingtorah/player_cdo/aid/878374/jewish/Welcome-Home.htm