# What other occasions cause forgiveness?

Tags: yom-kippur, wedding, forgiving-mechilah

Besides a person's wedding and Yom Kippur are there any other events which provide someone with atonement just by dint of the occasion itself?

Comment: You need Teshuva for forgiveness.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think the Midrash states that about one's wedding. Although one must be wary of reading to much radical implications into a Midrash.

Comment: @mevaqesh I suspect the OP is confusing "forgiveness" and "atonement", and hence arriving at fantastical ideas.

Comment: @DoubleAA I would assume that the former refers to absolution of guilt, and the latter, to makeing up for one's wrongdoing. Accordingly, it would be atonement which requires (by definition) teshuva; not forgiveness. (Did you mean to write: `You need Teshuva for atonement`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Becoming king causes one's sins to be forgiven (Yerushalmi Bikurim 11b)
2. The Gemara (Sanhedrin 14a) states that assuming certain positions of authority (the Gemara there is discussing *semicha*, but says it's also true about anyone who is "oleh lgedulah") causes one's sins to be forgiven (See Maharsha, however, for an alternate understanding of the Gemara).
3. Converting to Judaism causes one's prior sins to be forgiven (Yerushalmi Bikurim 11b).

Comment: you may have something to contribute to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6429/759

Answer (score 3):

death and getting killed by bais din

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911888/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-One.htm in the end

> death atones as [[Isaiah 22:14]](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15953#v=14) states: "It was revealed in my ears [by] the Lord of Hosts, surely this iniquity will not be atoned for until you die."

Comment: `death and getting killed by bais din` From my understanding, getting killed my _beit din_ usually results in death.

Comment: @mevaqesh :-) from my understanding somethings are not forgiven by death only by being killed by Bais Din , so you can say it is a better forgiveness